# Different Access Level for data sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to find a way to control data viewed by different users.
So I have five type of users, User with typeId 1 can view everything, whereas user with typeid 3 can view part of the data and so on.

Any suggestions how can I do this?

Control the data from my sql server itself,having if statements:

```
create procedure getAlldate(@typeid)
If @typeid=1 
Begin
select * from tblUsersDetails
End
```

or is there another way I could do this?

Comment: what is 'part of the data'? the limit is on the rows or on the columns? 'limited' users can access a limited number of rows only or a limited number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

- You can first create X database user roles for your X types of users. Look at [CREATE ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936.aspx)
- You then add users to their respective roles using [ALTER ROLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx) (or sp_addrolemember but it is deprecated)
- You can grant, deny or revoke rights on your objects to these User Roles. You grant Select on Table1 to RoleX like this:

  ```
  grant select on Table1 to RoleX
  ```
- If you need to give access to only part of a table or only some columns, you can first create a [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

  ```
  Create View View1 As
      Select col1, col2, col5, col10 
      From Table1
      Where col20 = 0
  ```
- Finally you can grant rights on the view to RoleX

  ```
  grant select on View1 to RoleX
  ```